# Unable to get back to graphical environment after changing desktop wallpaper style to newspaper

Tags: 13.10

I changed my desktop background style to "newspaper" and now I can't restore my graphical environment.

I only have the Kubuntu splash screen flashing and can only access command line with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

When a Linux graphical desktop environment breaks, it is usually caused by a bad setting in any of the following layers of the graphical environment:

- the window system
- the window manager
- the desktop manager
- the display manager

Read this [guide](http://journalxtra.com/linux/desktop-recovery/the-definitive-guide-to-getting-your-linux-desktop-back/) and try the methods stated in to restore your graphical environment back.